# Primeface-6.2.jar identified as Malicious

Tags: primefaces

I work with a company with pretty tight security. This morning while attempting to run my web application (JSF with primeface via Netbeans IDE), I was shown the following warning. The result is that the app now fails (duh).

[PF-6.2.jar Warning about being malicious](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPAqB.png)

I recall reading something about this a couple months ago, but I cannot find it. Does someone have a link with an explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because of this Cryptojacking Malware Injection:  https://www.primefaces.org/primefaces-el-injection-update/

PF 6.2 is fine and does not have this vulnerability so your tool may be marking it incorrectly as a false positive.  But double check to be sure.

Just in case I ran VirusTotal on it and it looks clean with 1 false positive:  [Virus Total Report on PF 6.2](https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/007bdea064f20cecad6773442a08062149b197d8a57329d070d945c06274f0cf/detection)

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you very much.